# ArangoDB could not start rebalance process

Tags: arangodb

On shards tab in ArangoDB web interface.
When I clicked the 'rebalance shards' button, it shows 'Could not start rebalance process'.

3 DB servers were clustered successfully.

Where can I find the error log file in this situation?

Comment: In ArangoDB versions 3.2.0 and 3.2.1 there was an issue with shard rebalancing. Using the button in the web UI triggered rebalancing, but it did not work due to an internal permissions issue.
That should be fixed with ArangoDB 3.2.2.
Where the logs are depends on what platform you are running ArangoDB on and how you deployed the instances.

Comment: I installed following on this manual https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/centos/ and running platform is CentOS 7. when 3 nodes clustered start up, it indicates /mypath/arangodb/. and in this dir, it has agent8531, coordinator8529, dbserver8530, setup.json file and directories.
p.s I execute below command to start up 3 nodes clustered.
On host A
arangodb --starter.data-dir=/mypath/arangodb/
On host B
arangodb --starter.join A(ip adress for A) --starter.data-dir=/mypath/arangodb/
On host C
arangodb --starter.join A(ip adress for A) --starter.data-dir=/mypath/arangodb/

Answer (score 0):

The log files are to be found in the same directories you mentioned agent8531, coordinator8529 and dbserver8530. They go by the name arangod.log